# Save image in hosted server in PHP

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on a project using ( LARAVEL 5.5) that creates QR codes and i would like to store the image that is built in the backend

this the code that creates the image and convert it to base64:

```
public function CreateQr($data)
{

    //Encrypting the data + creating the QR code with the Encrypted text
    $enc = (new CryptoController())->Encrypt($data);

    $src = base64_encode(QrCode::format('png')->size(250)->generate($enc));



    // the ID of the logged user
    $userID = $_SESSION['currentUserID'];




    $target = 'img/'.$userID.'/';


    if (!file_exists($target)) {
        mkdir($target, 0777, true);
    }

    copy($src, $target);



    return $src;

}
```

1. the CreateQr function receives a string text and convert that text
   into a crypted QR code
2. I would like to store the ( base64 ) images into a folder ( $target )

I have a seen almost every question in here but didn't find something closer to my needs. 
This is my first time using PHP so please do advise me on how to fix and approache this. thanx in advance

Comment: why would you save it as base64 ?

Comment: it is a project specification for better performance,

Comment: Does base64 encoding not make the image 33%(on average) larger?  -  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Padding

Answer (score 0):

The way that you are storing the files is recommended. Visit the Laravel's documentation in [File Storage](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem) on how to create and move files.

Also, In my opinion, do not convert the files to base64, store the QR image as you wo